# integrate Stripe into django project

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I've installed dj-stripe into my django project and I have some issues.
After installing, and according to the documentation, i've configured all settings and now I try to do a custom charge (I have no plan, user defines itself the amount)

Then, my code looks like (with 10 as amount to try):

```
@login_required()
def charge_balance(request):
    form = ChargeBalanceForm()
    if request.POST:
        form = ChargeBalanceForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            customer, created = Customer.get_or_create(subscriber=request.user)

            amount = Decimal(10.00)
            customer.charge(amount)

    return render(
        request,
        'merchant/charge_balance.html', {
            'form': form,
        })
```

It returns a `CardError` Exception `(Request req_Am9abuzxogBmI7: Cannot charge a customer that has no active card)`
I really do not understand what append, I wanted to find a page where user enter his card information but unfortunately I only have this exception.
Can someone help me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need a way for your users to enter their credit card info. Stripe has several. "checkout" has lets you use a form Stripe creates and "stripe.js" has a way you can have it appear in your own form. See the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js), they're quite good.

You can't use a regular django form and you have to make sure you don't save their credit card data to your server, which makes you legally liable.

Comment: thanks @jeremy-s I thought Stripe managed everything with a page redirection etc.